# Stopping HTML elements from becoming offset

Tags: javascript, html, css

```css
#h1 {
    float: center;
}
h2 {
    float: center;
}
p {
    font-family: "Comic Sans",sans-serif;
}
#div1 {   
    width: 7.5%;
    height: 100px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 12px;
    padding: 3%;
    border-bottom: 4px solid black;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 25px 25px;
    background-color: white;
    float:right;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    right: 0px;
}
#div2 {
    width: 7.5%;
    height: 100px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 15%;
    padding: 3%;
    border-bottom: 4px solid black;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 25px 25px;
    background-color: white;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    right: 0px;
}
#div3 {
    width: 7.5%;
    height: 100px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 30%;
    padding: 3%;
    border-bottom: 4px solid black;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 25px 25px;
    background-color: white;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    right: 0px;
}
#div4 {
    width: 101px;
    height: 101px;
    margin-left: 15%;
    padding: 1%;
    border-bottom: 4px solid black;
    border-radius: 0px 25px 25px 0px;
    background-color: white;
}
#div5 {
    height: 101px;
    padding: 10px;
    border-bottom: 4px solid black;
    border-radius: 0px 25px 25px 25px;
    background-color: white;
    margin: 1.5%;
}
#text {
    border-bottom: 4px solid black;
    padding: 1px;
    width: 13%;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 25px 25px 0px 0px;
    background-color: white;
    margin-left: 1.5%;
    color: #417cb8;
    text-align: center;
}
#tag1 {
    border-bottom: 4px solid black;
    padding: 1px;
    margin-right: 12px;
    width: 13%;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 25px 25px 0px 0px;
    background-color: white;
    float: right;
    position: absolute;
    margin-right: 5px;
    font-family: "Comic Sans",sans-serif;
    right: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #417cb8;
}
#tag2 {
    margin-right: 15%;
    padding: 5px;
    border-bottom: 4px solid black;
    width: 13%;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 25px 25px 0px 0px;
    background-color: white;
    position: absolute;
    font-family: "Comic Sans",sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    right: 0px;
    color: #417cb8;

}
#tag3 {
    margin-right: 30%;
    padding: 5px;
    border-bottom: 4px solid black;
    width: 13%;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 25px 25px 0px 0px;
    background-color: white;
    position: absolute;
    font-family: "Comic Sans",sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    right: 0px;
    color: #417cb8;
}
#tag4 {
    float: left;
    padding: 5px;
    border-bottom: 4px solid black;
    width: 10%;
    height: 101px;
    border-radius: 25px 0px 0px 25px;
    background-color: white;
    position: absolute;
    font-family: "Comic Sans",sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    margin-left: 1.5%;
    color: #417cb8;
    padding: 1%;
}
#element {
 float: left;
}
img.object {
 border: 1px solid #6496c8;
 background-color: white;
 border-radius: 25px;
 padding: 10px;
 height: 101;
 width: 101;
 float: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.21/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $('#element').draggable();
    $( "#div1" ).droppable({
        drop: function( event, ui ) {
          $( this )
            .addClass( "isDropped" )
            .html( "Dropped!" );
        }
    });
</script> <script>
function allowDrop(ev, div) {
    ev.preventDefault()
}

function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id)
}

function drop(ev, div) {
    ev.preventDefault()
 if(div == 'div4') 
 {
  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text")
  var element = document.getElementById(data)
  element.parentNode.removeChild(element)
 }
 else if (div == 'div5') {
  if(document.getElementById(div).innerHTML <= 5)
  {
   var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text")
   ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data))
  }
 }
 else if (div == 'element')
 {
  
 }
 else
 {
  if(document.getElementById(div).innerHTML <= 5)
  {
   var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text")
   ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data))
  }
 }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div style="border: 1px solid black; border-radius: 30px; background-color: #6496c8;">

<h2 style="float: center; text-align: center; border-bottom: 4px solid black; width: 275px; height: 65px; border-radius: 25px 0px 0px 0px; background-color: white; margin-left: 1.5%;"><font style="text-align:center;" face="verdana" color="#417cb8" size=30>Organiser</font></h2>

<div id="tag1"><font size="7">Now</font></div><br><br><br><br>
<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event, 'div1')" ondragover="allowDrop(event, 'div1')"></div>

<div id="tag2"><font size="7">Next</font></div><br><br><br><br>
<div id="div2" ondrop="drop(event, 'div2')" ondragover="allowDrop(event, 'div2')"></div>
<div id="tag3"><font size="7">After</font></div><br><br><br><br>
<div id="div3" ondrop="drop(event, 'div3')" ondragover="allowDrop(event, 'div3')"></div>

<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<p id="text"><font size="7">To Do</font></p>

<p id="div5" ondrop="drop(event, 'div1')" ondragover="allowDrop(event, 'div1')" overflow="Scroll">
<img class="object" src="ABC.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag1" width="100" height="100">
<img class="object" src="pencil.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag2" width="100" height="100">
<img class="object" src="recycle.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag3" width="100" height="100">
<img class="object" src="apple.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag4" width="100" height="100">

<br><br><p><div id = "tag4"><font size="10">Done</font></div>
<div id="div4" ondrop="drop(event, 'div4')" ondragover="allowDrop(event, 'div4')"><img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/tools-solid-icons-vol-2/72/59-512.png" height=100px width=100px></div><br>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

When i drag and drop elements back into the starting div, they become offset, can anybody explain why please? I have tried changing tags to classes, i have tried changing drag and drop options to no avail.

Comment: float:center is not a thing,

Comment: @mlegg - wouldn't life just be a little simpler though if it was? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 4 images within the `<p>` element. Those images are followed by line breaks `<br><br>` because your `<p>` is not properly closed. so the browser places the `</p>` tag right after the `<br><br>` instead of before like I image you meant for,

When you move the image out of the `<p>` and then back in, it is placed after the line break now, instead of before it. this causes the image to move to the next line.

All you need to do is place a `</p>` right before those `<br><br>` or delete the line breaks altogether.

Comment: Thanks! Worked just as expected.... I think partially through development I had a use for those BR tags

Comment: @RichardZheng - glad I could help, If my answer solved your problem it would be great if you could accept it as the answer.

Comment: @RichardZheng no problem. we all start somewhere, welcome to the community.

Comment: By any chance... Do you know how to make touch work  with HTML? It does not seem to work ATM, but is fine on PC

Comment: @RichardZheng You'll want to look at "Event Listeners" in javascript. specifically "touchstart", "touchmove", and "touchend". Also, just so ya know, it's technically frowned upon for getting off-topic in the comments like this. It's recommended to just start a new question.